# Laravel blade does not respect date cast formatting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a birth date field in users table

```
$table->date('dob');
```

User model has Casts

```
protected $casts = [
        'dob' => 'date:d-m-Y'
    ];
```

In Blade,

```
{{$user->dob}}
```

I was expecting 26-11-2019
but found it shows 2019-11-26 00:00:00

Why I need to format the date again in blade when display?

What did I miss? 
Or what I was expecting, is not the purpose of formatting?

Answer (score 3):

`protected $casts = [...]` tells Laravel to treat the properties as `Carbon` instances, but you still need to format them:

```
{{ $user->dob->format('d-m-Y') }}
```

As far as I'm aware, there isn't a way to output a default format, unless you use an `accessor`:

In your `User.php` model:

```
public function getDobFormattedAttribute(){
  return $this->dob->format('y-m-D');
}
```

Then in your view:

```
{{ $user->dob_formatted }}
```

Comment: Thanks... but I was looking for something so that I do not need to write these...

Answer (score 2):

Date casting uses only for arrays or JSON, as explained here:

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

You can try to do it via mutator:

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

```php
protected $dates = [
    'dob', // it will be 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
];

protected $dateFormat = 'd-m-Y'; // but you can redefine it
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. So cast formatting is only for arrays or JSON.
First I used  $casts = [
        'dob' => 'date'
    ];

But it fails the assertDatabaseHas test.
Need to see if you solution make the test pass....

Comment: This will also affect `created_at` and `updated_at` is those are present.

Comment: It will cause problems if affect created_at. So this is not a good approach to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

that will only work when you use a `->toArray()` or `->toJson()` on the object or collection in question, from the doc here https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

A way around that of you weren't using any of the above function call is to create an accessor or getter method in the model.

```
    use Carbon\Carbon; // import the Carbon lib.


    protected $dates = ['dob'];

    public function getDobAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $value);
    }
```